# Nan values when I merge these data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I am want to merge two data frames in pandas but I am getting Nan values.

```
data_orig = url
data_orig.head(3) #data frame 1

   sex  length  diameter    height      
0   M   0.455   0.365      0.095    
1   M   0.350   0.265      0.090    
2   F   0.530   0.420      0.135    


def parse_label(label):
    options = {'I': 0, 'F': 1, 'M': 2}
    return options[label]

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['sex'] = data_orig['sex'].map(parse_label)

data.head() #data frame 2

    sex
0   2
1   2
2   1
3   2

pd.merge(data, data_orig, on ='sex', how= 'left')

sex length  diameter    height  
2    NaN     NaN         NaN    
2    NaN     NaN         NaN
```

Why do I get NaN values in my merged data frame??

I need a data frame like this, how do i do that??

```
  sex  length   diameter  height
    2   0.455    0.365     0.095
    2   0.350    0.265     0.090
```

Comment: Independent of your actual question, you don't need the `parse_label` function. `map` also works with dictionaries directly, like `data_org['sex'].map({'I': 0, 'F': 1, 'M': 2})`.

Comment: @filmor I am getting an Nan value if I apply this map function directly to my data_org data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `NaN` values because there are no matches for your values in the left hand side df with the right hand side df:

```
In [3]:
   data

Out[3]:
   sex
0    2
1    2
2    1
In [4]:

df
Out[4]:
  sex  length  diameter  height
0   M   0.455     0.365   0.095
1   M   0.350     0.265   0.090
2   F   0.530     0.420   0.135
```

There are no matches for 'M' with the corresponding int value 2.
It's unclear what you are trying to do here, you performed a conversion of your sex character values to their corresponding int value and then you try to merge this back, why not just convert them in the orig df:

```
In [6]:

df['sex'] = df['sex'].map(parse_label)
df
Out[6]:
   sex  length  diameter  height
0    2   0.455     0.365   0.095
1    2   0.350     0.265   0.090
2    1   0.530     0.420   0.135
```

Comment: If I do that directly on my original data set ( data_orig) I am getting a key error '2'.

Comment: @user3796494 sorry you're telling me that you get that error on your original df? Also it's unnecessary to define a function to perform the mapping if you already have a dict so `data_orig['sex'] = data_orig['sex'].map({'I': 0, 'F': 1, 'M': 2})`, if you are still getting a key error, it means your dict does not cover all values and in fact you should've got a key error running your code originally, can you update your post with the ouput from `data_orig['sex'].unique()`

Comment: @user3796494 specifically it looks like you already have some values in your `data_orig['sex']` column already converted if you have a `KeyError` for `2`

Comment: I got it!! I rectified my problem,  already there were certain values 2 in my original df.